# Adding new item in carousel adds new row in Angular4

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am working in an Angular4 application,In this I have a carousel were I show the products and product name and price .Currently I have 6 products (3+3).I have 2 buttons if I clicked on left carousel will show 3 products from left side for right button will show 3 products from right ride.

The problem is when I add a new product carousel generate a new row instead showing like in the line of products.

How to resolve is .

HTML

```
 <section class="carousel slide"  id="myCarousel">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-right mb-4">
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary carousel-control left"  href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" title="go back"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"  title="more"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                    </div>      
                </div>   
            </div>

            <div class="container p-t-0 m-t-2 carousel-inner">
                <div class="row row-equal carousel-item active m-t-0">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img-top card-img-top-250 one">
                                <img routerLink="/my-cart"  class="img-fluid" src="assets/Images/Popular_Products/iPhone1.jpg" alt="Carousel 1">
                                <img routerLink="/my-cart" (click)="getProductName(Pname1)" class="img-fluid two" src="assets/Images/Popular_Products/iPhone2.jpg" alt="Carousel 1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-block pt-2">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center card-text">
                                   <span #Pname1>iPhone</span>
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    3433 $
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img-top card-img-top-250 one">
                                <img routerLink="/my-cart" class="img-fluid" src="assets/Images/Popular_Products/indianSpices1.jpg" alt="Carousel 1">
                                <img routerLink="/my-cart" (click)="getProductName(Pname)" class="img-fluid two" src="assets/Images/Popular_Products/indianSpices2.jpg" alt="Carousel 1">
                            </div>
                             <div class="card-block pt-2">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center card-text">
                                   <span #Pname>Indian Spices</span>
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    747 $
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img-top card-img-top-250 one">
                                <img  class="img-fluid" src="assets/Images/Popular_Products/6.jpg" alt="Carousel 1">
                                <img routerLink="/my-cart"  class="img-fluid two" src="assets/Images/Popular_Products/10.jpg" alt="Carousel 1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-block pt-2">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center card-text">
                                   <span>Home Appliances</span>
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    <span >4500 $</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="row row-equal carousel-item m-t-0">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img-top card-img-top-250 one">
                                <img routerLink="/my-cart" class="img-fluid" src="assets/Images/Popular_Products/8.jpg" alt="Carousel 1">
                                <img routerLink="/my-cart" class="img-fluid two" src="assets/Images/Popular_Products/9.jpg" alt="Carousel 1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-block pt-2">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center card-text">
                                    Bicycles
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    2329 $
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img-top card-img-top-250 one">
                                <img routerLink="/my-cart" class="img-fluid" src="assets/Images/Popular_Products/5.jpg" alt="Carousel 1">
                                <img routerLink="/my-cart" class="img-fluid two" src="assets/Images/Popular_Products/12.jpg" alt="Carousel 1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-block pt-2">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center card-text">
                                    Electronic Items
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    8333 $
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img-top card-img-top-250 one">
                                <img routerLink="/my-cart" class="img-fluid" src="assets/Images/Popular_Products/2.jpg" alt="Carousel 1">
                                <img routerLink="/my-cart" class="img-fluid two" src="assets/Images/Popular_Products/7.jpg" alt="Carousel 1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-block pt-2">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center card-text">
                                    Natural Oils
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    5435 $
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Here you can find the stackblitz file https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n6ecud?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Edit your question and put the link as part of it and not as comment, it's pretty easy to miss your link as a comment. Also, I did not see any template kind of code, your whole HTML looks like static content and not interacting with the data in your angular controller.

Comment: @PM. here I gave the static code only ,If I give the dynamic code readers can't access my API

Comment: Dynamic code will help to understand your template, which in turn explain how it behaves same till 3 item (or multiple of 3) but differently for additional item. For example part, static html makes sense.

Comment: Is this the behaviour https://angular-k16ix9.stackblitz.io you want ?

Comment: @Afsar,yes exactly, but I want, I can able to add more products in it

Comment: @Afsar,Actually I am binding the products from API ,But here I used to show the static code .If I get the idea I will implement it

Comment: @Nikson: then you have to create a new div with  class="row row-equal carousel-item" and append new items into it

Answer (score 0):

In stackblitz, there's no button to add a new product. Either you are adding the new product manually or the code is missed from the solution.

If adding manually, possibly you are adding it as a new row instead of another column. Since you are using bootstrap layout, your code divides the screen area in 12 parts, and each image is using 4 parts (sm-12, sm-4 respectively). Now when you add another product, that creates a new row since there's no space remaining in the current row.

To fix this out, rather than giving part by part allocation, give a fixed size to each product card, and then let the whole scroll horizontally.

Or, create another sm-12 row (3rd carousal) and add elements to it. You will be required to create a component hosting 3 products and each left/right button will cycle in the main carousal. Any product addition will go in the empty component and once filled, will create another instance to host the product.

--- pseudo code below, customize with actual values ----

```
@Component( {} }
export class ProductsContainerComponent {
    products: Product[]

// template shows 3 products
}

@Component()
export class ProductCarousalComponent {
     carousal: ProductsContainerComponent[]

     btnPrevious, btnNext: Button => Each set the current pointer to a given container in list, which gets displayed

     addNewProduct() {
ProductsContainerComponent container;
carousal.each(prod => if (prod.products.length < 3) { container = prod; break; } );
if (container == null)
   {  container = new ProductsContainerComponent();  carousal.push (container); }

// construct your new product here (url, images, text etc)
container.products.push (new Product() );

}
```

Comment: I didn't say that I have a button for adding new item

Comment: Would take some time, can you just abstract the template to show a set of 3 items into a single component, and then host this component inside another (list of components which get cycled)

Comment: I couldn't get you

Comment: Please see pseudo code in the edited answer, you would need to update it with actual values